# Json output array to php variable

Tags: php, json, variables, jsonencoder

prob an easy fix, but I'm stuck.

So `print_r($data) =`

```
stdClass Object (
    [code] => 200000
    [data] => stdClass Object (
        [accountEquity] => 111
        [unrealisedPNL] => 111
        [marginBalance] => 111
        [positionMargin] => 111
        [orderMargin] => 0
        [frozenFunds] => 0
        [availableBalance] => 111
        [currency] => xxx
    )
)
```

And echo `$data->code` outputs '`20000`'

But I can not get the other 'variables' to work.
Ive tried:

```
$data->code->data->accountEquity

$data[1]->accountEquity

$data->code->data->accountEquity
```

What is the right format to get those other values?

Thank you. gr Mike

Comment: Try restructuring your debug output, you'll see the solution pretty quickly then (I have edited your question). Otherwise, it would most likely help you to use a debugger for whatever IDE you are working with. Just Google "debug php with [your ide here]"

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) preferably in a [Stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get `accountEquity` is

```
$data->data->accountEquity
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way to access `accountEquity` is:

```
$data->data->accountEquity
```

But you could also cast the object to an array with:

```
$data = (array) $data;
```

Then `accountEquity` is reached by:

```
$data['data']['accountEquity']
```

Comment: Glad i could help and welcome to SO. Please select my answer so the question is finished. Happy coding.